# Запрет создания (стекового) массива неизвестной длины

Tags: c++, массивы, gcc, mingw, codeblocks

Необходимо создать массив, размер которого заранее неизвестен (например, его размер будет введён с клавиатуры). Наивное решение (неправильное):

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
int mas[n];
```

Этот способ на некоторых компиляторах работает (например, на gcc). Какой флаг компиляции нужно выставить, чтобы на это действие получить warning ? А лучше ошибку компиляции (чтобы -Werror не ставить просто так).

Это необходимо в учебных целях, чтобы не объяснять детям тонкости стандарта и нестандартных расширений компиляторов. Хочется им просто сказать, что так делать нельзя, что компилятор это не скомпилирует (и защититься от фейла с gcc :) ).

Конкретнее, это будет использоваться в среде CodeBlocks, там компилятор MinGW.

Comment: Достаточно требовать соответствия стандарту.

Массив неизвестной длины в С++ запрещен.

Comment: `-pedantic-error` попробуйте.

Comment: @Harry , Дети 8 класса, их лучше не грузить стандартом, им итак нелегко это всё осваивать... )

Comment: Детей 8 класса, имхо, рано грузить плюсами.

Comment: *"просто сказать, что так делать нельзя"* - для целей обучения лучше рассказать почему может понадобится так делать, почему где-то разрешено, а в стандарте - нет, и какие есть альтернативы.

Comment: Ну не знаю. У меня у малого в прошлом году тоже в 8 классе начались плюсы - но попытки создавать массив переменной длины за ним ни разу не замечал... И вообще, они вектор освоили раньше массива, за что я учительнице признателен :) Да и говоря о требовании соответствия стандарту я имел в виду - требовать от компилятора.

Comment: @älёxölüt , это да, но в этом вопросе я только исполнитель, вот и пытаюсь, облегчить им понимание...

Comment: @Harry , поддерживаю, но в корректировке программы у меня мало возможностей, поэтому придётся лишь аккуратно дополнять то, что выдали )

Comment: @VTT , про стандарт я бы детям такого возраста пока не стал упоминать, там итак информации слишком много, а стандарт их совсем запутает.

Comment: @zcorvid Откуда они вообще узнали про такую возможность?.. Если рассказал учитель - то бессмысленное занятие. Если хакерята нашлись - то они и ключики снимут :) Как-то тут концы с концами не сходятся... Imho, конечно...

Comment: Ну так чтобы не запутывались, надо пояснять, откуда ноги растут. А то с одними запретами получится как с Абалкиным.

Comment: Примеры подобные этому и здесь былвали в вопросах

Comment: @zcorvid, а что врать нехорошо, вы своим ученикам не говорите?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `-pedantic` или `-Wvla`:

```
 warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'mas' [-Wvla]
```

Comment: Для ошибки лучше `-pedantic-error`

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. Добавьте, пожалуйста, в ответ информацию и про `-pedantic-error` , для полноты.